# How to simple login on Google via HTTP connection with Android?

Tags: java, android, http, authentication

I see several questions on how to login on google, but all the answers speak about authentication and google api. I want a simple login on google, just to check if the user exists or not (I do not intend to do anything with the user account (access email, etc ...). The user fills out the email and password when they click the login button through a http connection logging is done.
The problem is that even if I put the wrong email or password it continues logging. I do not know if I'm using the wrong google website to login or what.

Here is the function call and google login website:

```
new LoginIntoGoogle().execute(new String[] {"https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?"});
```

This is what the code is doing:

```
private class LoginIntoGoogle extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        // Start HTTP connection and send the database to the web server
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url[0]);

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", ""+userEmail));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Passwd", ""+passtext.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("signIn", "Login"));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() < 300 && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() >= 200) {
               System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

               Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
               editor.putString("login_status", "Logged into your google account");
               editor.commit();

               return "Logged into your google account";
            }
            else {
               Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
               editor.putString("login_status", "Problem to login into your google account");
               editor.commit();

               return "Problem to login into your google account";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use encryption since you are transferring personal data over the internet.

You should look int [Oauth](http://oauth.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the Google playstore services released recently. Read the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/) .
Checkout this [video from Google IO about PlayStore services](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lc_Eme_xpr4).

Hope this helps.